# WPF Window in DLL cannot load its associated resource DLL

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF dll, built with .NET 4.0, with a Window class that I need to localize.
I am using Sisulizer to build the my resource dlls but I cannot get these resource dlls to load for the dll.

Based on reading several ariticles I have tried the following:

Set the CurrentUICulture and CurrentCulture (I have set one and both with no luck) in WPF dll before loading the Window.

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fr-FR");
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fr-FR");
```

Set the Culture for my resources.

```
Properties.Resources.Culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fr-FR");
```

I have created folders with names fr and fr-FR below where I place my WPF EXE.
Lastly my WPF EXE does get localized to French using a different resource dll placed in the "fr" and "fr.FR" folder. When I open the Window in the DLL the hard coded text does not change and a resource string I load at runtime in my ViewModel and display in my view also does not get translated.

Can anyone suggest how to do this?